# Jupyter Notebook: automatically saves all images

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I need most images in my jupyter notebook, https://cdn.rawgit.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/master/output_HTML/marham.html

The problem is that there are too many, and saving them one by one, by command or manually is very time-consuming.

Is there a way to automatically save all images in a notebook?

For example, maybe I can make a magic command

```
%matplotlib autosave
```

and the images would be saved sequentially, named as 1.pic, 2.pic ... in the dir of the notebook.

Addtionally, what is the recommand image format for publishing? It would be good if the image could be edit, change styles, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [convert](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) option of Jupyter. The syntax is

```
jupyter nbconvert --to FORMAT notebook.ipynb
```

The default is html, so it will convert your images to PNG files.
You can also use a LaTeX conversion

```
jupyter nbconvert --to latex notebook.ipynb
```

Alternatively, you can use the menu `File>>Download as`, and use Markdown, reSTructured Text or LaTeX there.

Regarding the format for publication, it depends on the journal you're aiming. My suggestion would be to export your images as SVG when you want to edit later. Inkscape can be used for this purpose), and they can be embedded in LibreOffice. Use PDF when you want them ready to go. Vector graphics are generally better for the type of graphics in your notebook. If you're planning to use MS Word, then you might want to convert the graphics from SVG to EMF as an intermediate step.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it correctly. As I remember, the `rawgit` file I gave is actually `nbconvert` into html. And, sadly, the images are in `base64`, not PNG. And they are still in html file, I need to save them one by one (or maybe a js script to do the trick?). So did I make the convert correctly?

Comment: I just converted a notebook to LaTeX and it created a folder and a PNG file for each image. And yes, you can probably write a script to generate the files from your html code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pipeline to do the following:

1. save the notebook (so that nbconvert can see the output images)
2. create a markdown file and the corresponding images with nbconvert.
3. delete the temporary files and reoder the images.

```py
#pip install ipylab
#pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
from ipylab import JupyterFrontEnd
from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil


app = JupyterFrontEnd()
app.commands.execute('docmanager:save')
#### now a new cell, because the notebook is only saved in the end of the cell execution.

file_name = "00_dilate" # define notebook name

folder_name = file_name + "_files"
notebook_name = file_name + ".ipynb"
markdown_name = file_name + ".md"
base_directory = Path.cwd() / folder_name
target_directory = Path.cwd() / "imgs" 

!jupyter nbconvert $notebook_name --to markdown

!rm -r $target_directory # delete previously saved images

target_directory.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

paths = sorted(Path(base_directory).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime) #sort files after name
for num, p in enumerate(paths):
    to_path = target_directory /  f"{file_name}_{num:03}.png" 
    shutil.copy(p,  to_path)
    
!rm -r $markdown_name  #delete temp files
!rm -r $folder_name
```