# How to export images in Jupyter notebook attachment:media to disk files?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook with some images in the attachment that look like this:

```
<img src="attachment:media/image20.png" style="width:2.83in;height:2.85in" />
```

I wanted to use this image elsewhere, but I couldn't find the image file `image20.png` or the `media` folder anywhere on the hard drive. I guess the image file is somewhere inside the `.ipynb` itself.

My question is:

*How to export the image file referenced by `attachment:media/...` to an actual `.png` file on the disk?*

Note: I searched around on SO, and only found answers to export the output of a cell. e.g.

[Jupyter Notebook: automatically saves all images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166236)

(, ... or saving the output of a maplotlib plot function.)

But the images above are not from the output of any code cell or code. I can see the image in the notebook, but not the actual `.png` file in the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view as text and extract the value from a JSON dictionary under keyword "image/png". This has been automated for use from the command line in the Junix repo https://github.com/damienmarlier51/Junix as described by the author at

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/export-images-from-jupyter-notebook-with-a-single-command-422db2b66e92